# Проверка на null в питоне

Tags: python

Есть код питона который считывает с xls файла поля

Скрипт работает, но возникает проблемы при присутствии пустых полей в файле

Скрипт не считывает поля если в файле есть пустое поле

Мой код , здесь к примеру поле  NORD пустое:

```
from msexcel8com import *
def convert(dsIn, dsOut):
 import sys
 sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')   
 import msexcel8com
 xlsApp = msexcel8com.Application()
 xlsApp.Workbooks.Open(unicode(dsIn["PATH_TO_XLS"]))
 xlsWorkbook = xlsApp.Workbooks.Item(1)
 xlsWorksheet = xlsWorkbook.Worksheets.Item(1)
 xlsWorksheet.Cells.SpecialCells(11,None).Activate()
 rowsCount = xlsApp.ActiveCell.Row
 import msxml2
 dsOut.clear()
 outXML = msxml2.DOMDocument()
 RootNode = outXML.createElement('MSG')
 RootNode.setAttribute('FORMAT', 'IMPORT_LN')
 ChildNodes = outXML.appendChild(RootNode)
 i, k, c = 1, 1, 2
 while (i < rowsCount):
  i = i + 1
  if k > c:
   k = 0;
   dsOut.append()
   dsOut['XML_OUT'] = unicode.encode(outXML.xml, "utf-8" )
   outXML = msxml2.DOMDocument()
   RootNode = outXML.createElement('MSG')
   RootNode.setAttribute('FORMAT', 'IMPORT_LN')
   ChildNodes = outXML.appendChild(RootNode)
  try:
      TMPNode = outXML.createElement('CLIENT')
      TMPNode.setAttribute('NCODE',xlsWorksheet.Cells.Item(i,1).Value)
      TMPNode.setAttribute('NORD', xlsWorksheet.Cells.Item(i,2).Value)
      ChildNodes.appendChild(TMPNode)
      k = k + 1
  except Exception, e:
      print e;
 dsOut.append()
 dsOut['XML_OUT'] = unicode.encode(outXML.xml, "utf-8" )
 try:
   xlsApp.Workbooks.Close()
 except Exception, e:
   print e;
 try:
   xlsApp.Quit()
 except Exception, e:
   print e;
```

Как сделать чтобы даже если есть пустое поле возвращать как null и остальные значении?

Comment: Тут не все разбираются в библиотеках вроде `msexcel8com`, поэтому давайте точнее, что значит `не считывает поля`? Возникает ошибка? Где и какая конкретно?

Comment: В каком месте возникает ошибка? И какая?

Comment: @Jazzis, имелось ввиду данный скрипт нужен для считывание значении с xls файла, счс если хоть одно изперечисленных полей пусто то питон не считывает остальные поля